# Prevent Kubernetes from schedulling everything to the same node

Tags: kubernetes

So I have 4 nodes currently, and Kubernetes, for some reason, decides to always schedule everything to the same node.

I'm not talking about replicas of the same deployment, so `topologySpreadConstraints` wouldn't apply there. In fact, when I scale up a deployment to several replicas, they get scheduled to different nodes. However, any new deployment and any new volume always go to the same node.

Affinity constraints also work, if I configure a pod to only schedule to a specific node (different from the usual one) it works fine. But anything else, goes to the same node. Is this considered normal? The node is at 90% utilization, and even when it crashes completely, Kubernetes happily schedules everything to it again.

Comment: Define "anything else".

Comment: All new `Deployment`'s `Pod`s  go to the same node by default, all created `Volume`s get mounted on the same node. Only when a `Deployment` is scaled to several replicas do they get spread across nodes, but the first replica always goes to the first one. I've patched the situation temporarily by limiting the number of pods on the node.

Comment: Do you have access to the scheduler's config? Might want to check out the docs on the [Kubernetes Scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/).

Comment: I have access since I installed the cluster myself. However, I wouldn't know what to look for without further guidance. Do you have any suggestions? The closest indication of any issue I can find are some errors of `error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-scheduler` in `kube-scheduler` pods, but these are from long ago.

Comment: Can you try setting logging level (`--v`) to `10`?

I can see at least 1 scenario where the [default score plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/scheduling/config/#scheduling-plugins) result in a situation where the 1st node is always selected.

Log level 10 should show us the scoring info we need as per [code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/121d24cfc76ca1c03f89ceb70e72ee9de7ab465f/pkg/scheduler/schedule_one.go#L692-L700).

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Too much work lately. Thanks to your comment I found out that the `PodTopologySpread` is scoring that node much higher than any other. I don't know how it can be so since I never declared one! I'll try to investigate it further and see if I can solve it but I'll also gladly take any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this was a very specific issue, and I'm not sure whether I actually resolved it, but it seems to be working now.

This was a cluster deployed on hetzner and using the [hetzner cloud controller manager](https://github.com/hetznercloud/hcloud-cloud-controller-manager). I had been removing and adding nodes to the cluster and, as it turns out, I forgot to add the flag `--cloud-provider=external` to this one's `kubelet`

This issue is pretty [well known](https://github.com/hetznercloud/hcloud-cloud-controller-manager/issues/80). It was specifically showing as a "missing prefix" event, so I never thought it was related.

To solve it, adding the flag and restarting the `kubelet` was not enough for me. So I had to drain the node, remove it from the cluster, build it from scratch and re-join it then with the correct flag. This not only solved the "missing prefix" issue, but it also seems to have also solved the scheduling issue, though I'm not sure why.